# What are good alternatives to GV Design Sprints?

Tags: design-process, design-frameworks

I'm currently reading "Sprint: How to Solve Big Problems and Test New Ideas in Just Five Days". I'd like to learn more about other product design frameworks (for example Co-Design http://bit.ly/226tM8O).

Can you please recommend or share examples of other design frameworks that you have personally used within your organizations?

Comment: BTW, check out Design Sprint 2.0: https://ajsmart.com/design-sprint-2-0/. It's a refined take on the methodology

Answer (score 3):

The [Jobs-to-be-Done Framework](https://jtbd.info/) is one with which I have recently become familiar. There's a book and a website. It's based around task-analysis to determine customer motivation.